Fastest C++ way to convert string to vector of floats
I have a large string containing float values separated by spaces. What is the fastest way in modern C++ to convert it to vector of floats?
This is a sample to test in github
For now the fastest way I know:
const char* begin_z = string_of_floats.c_str();
char* end_z = NULL;
errno = 0;
float z = strtod(begin_z, &end_z);

Floats.push_back(abs(z));
while (errno == 0 && end_z != begin_z)
{
    begin_z = end_z;
    z = strtod(begin_z, &end_z);
    Floats.push_back(z);
}
Floats.pop_back();


std::from_chars - "This is intended to allow the fastest possible implementation that is useful in common high-throughput contexts such as text-based interchange"

Have you tried anything yet?  Did you verify that converting the std::string is actually your bottleneck?

@ted-lyngmo thank you, could you please provide code example?

@stephen-newell yes, I have added what I am using now, but it is still not fast as I want. Basically I have big txt file, converting it to string then to vector of floats. And this last operation occupy longest time.

When you are done, don't forget to crank up the optimizer and profile. Sometimes the stuff that should be fastest... isn't. Or isn't fast enough. Either way, a profiler will tell you where you need to start looking to make significant improvements.

Stuffing into the vector is the big time-eater? Assuming the code is being optimized, update the question to start the optimization level used, this will probably turn out to be allocation and copy costs as the vector is resized. You may be able to mitigate this with some assumptions about the number of inputs coming and reserve storage ahead of time.

Just to drive the point home: Make sure you're compiling with optimization enabled. Far too many, "Why is my code slow?" questions are trivially answered with "Turn on the optimizer" after an exchange that goes something like, "What optimization compiler flags are you using?" "Uhm... What's an optimization compiler flag?"

Read 1 chunk, convert to float in another thread concurrently. Read next chunk concurrently. Repeat.

There is a bit of complexity to the above. Since you're reading text and likely don't know ahead of time where each token in the file ends, odds are high that when you read a chunk, that chunk will end in the middle of a number. The standard text-to-number conversion tools will not know or care if part of a number is missing and will be found in the next chunk. The last parsed token will have to be held over to be processed with the next chunk to make sure all of the token has been converted.

Rather than using std::strtod(), I would probably just make/find a custom std::streambuf that holds a pointer to string_of_floats's data, and then use it with std::istream with operator>> to read the floats.

You can use std::from_chars which "is intended to allow the fastest possible implementation that is useful in common high-throughput contexts such as text-based interchange".
Example:
#include <charconv>   // std::from_chars
#include <cstring>
#include <filesystem>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

std::vector<float> get_it(const std::filesystem::path& filename) {
    std::vector<float> result;
    { // reserve based on file size:
        std::error_code ec;
        auto size = std::filesystem::file_size(filename, ec);
        if(ec) {
            std::cerr << filename << ": " << ec.message() << '\n';
            return result;
        }
        result.reserve(size / 12); // approximation
    }

    std::ifstream is(filename);
    if(!is) {
        std::cerr << filename << ": " << std::strerror(errno) << '\n';
        return result;
    }

    // read lines until it fails
    std::string line;
    while(std::getline(is, line)) {
        const char* first = line.c_str();
        const char* const last = first + line.size();

        // convert all words in this line to floats
        float value;
        for(std::from_chars_result res;
            (res = std::from_chars(first, last, value)), res.ec == std::errc{};
            first = res.ptr + 1) // +1 to step over the space
        {
            result.push_back(value);
            if(res.ptr == last) break;
        }
    }
    return result;
}

You could then measure how long it takes to read the whole file:
#include <chrono>

int main() {
    auto start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    auto res = get_it("string of floats.GRDECL");
    std::chrono::duration<double> dur(std::chrono::steady_clock::now() - start);
    std::cout << "Got " << res.size() << " floats in " << dur << '.' << '\n';
}

Possible output:
Got 1667704 floats in 0.0958612s.


If your input may contain double spaces you may rewrite the inner for loop to look for the first non-space (as determined by std::isspace) character:
for(std::from_chars_result res;
    (res = std::from_chars(first, last, value)), res.ec == std::errc{};)
{
    result.push_back(value);
    if(res.ptr == last) break;

    // find the first non-space character:
    first = std::find_if_not(res.ptr + 1, last, [](unsigned char ch) {
        return std::isspace(ch);
    });
}


thank you a lot for your answer, but what if within string I have not only regular spaces but also double spaces?

@RuslanIbragimov You're welcome. I updated the answer to take care of that.

@RuslanIbragimov Did you try out the version taking care of double spaces?

Thank you again, unfortunately I could not, in '[](unsigned char ch)' part I am getting error "a local lambda is not allowed in a member function of a managed class"

@RuslanIbragimov An inline function will provide the same service.

@RuslanIbragimov Did you get it working? Btw, when you say managed class, does that mean that you are using C++/CLI, not C++ ?

yes, thank you, finally got it working, but I compared it with my strtod variant and it turned out to be 10 times longer.. But I am doing it wrong, I checked generated vectors sizes in both variants, they are equal. Yes, I use CLI.

@RuslanIbragimov Ok. When you ask about C++/CLI be sure to use the [c++-cli] tag. C++ Isn't the same language.
